# get the creator of a branch in gitlab ( list of branch)

Tags: gitlab, branch

How can I know who is created the branch in gitlab 
I try this command : git for-each-ref --format='%(authorname) %09 -%(refname)' | sort 
but it list the last commits
any help please !! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use [WebHooks](https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/integrations/webhooks) from Settings -> Integrations on push event?

Comment: thanks for your response, but there isn't the solution !! any other suggestion please